# How do I create a custom editor for VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm attempting to build a visual studio extension. My project is created from the "VSIX Project" template.

According to the documentation there should be a template for a custom editor but I am not finding it and failing at googling it. Is there something I'm missing beyond the SDK or am I misreading the documentation?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166460.aspx

> To create a VSPackage using the Visual Studio Package template
>
> 1.Create a project with the Visual Studio Package template. For more information about using this template, see Creating an Extension with
>   a Menu Command.
>
> 2.Select the Custom Editor option and click Next. The Editor Options page is displayed.
>
> 3.Type the name of your editor in the Editor Name box. Type the file extension that you want to be associated with your editor in the File
>   Extension box. Your editor is available for files with this extension.
>   The file extension is registered for Visual Studio only, not for
>   Windows. Type the default file name for new documents created with
>   your editor in the Default File Name box.
>
> 4.Click Finish to create your VSPackage in the folder that you specified.

[image: Available Templates]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extensibility project templates were refactored into item templates in an effort to make the templates more usable. For example, you can add multiple items like commands, toolwindows etc to a single project.

That documentation is definitely outdated. I'd recommend using the Editor_With_Toolbox sample, or perhaps the WPFDesigner_XML sample (from the [VS Extensibility Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples)), as a starting point for your project.

Comment: The Editor_With_Toolbox sample is horrible in that it takes it for serious to use a RichTextBox as the editor control. I'm having trouble using an IWpfTextView aka core editor for my extension, do you know any links about that? I wish the documentation on MS Docs wouldn't be so outdated about this.

Comment: Yea, is there any minimal example/old template? WPFDesigner_XML is also not ideal. I just would like to know how to place nude WPF window/view as an editor and it's hard to tell what is really needed and what is extra xml stuff...

Answer (score 3):

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn916149.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It seems like the ability to create custom editors in any language but C++ was removed in VS2015.

I think the microsoft dokumentation, for these topics, is outdated.

Comment: They only say the templates are not available not that you can't write them in other languages "The VSPackage project template no longer supports C# or Visual Basic projects. For more information, see Visual Studio SDK." and in almost 2019 it's still not updated.. :/

Comment: 2021 and I'm still waiting for a solution to this. I have a custom editor which is basically not a custom editor since it only applies classifications and some custom completion. You can't right click a file and 'open with' since there is no custom editor support. The documentation is very outdated.